# SCP overwrites files with dollar signs

Tags: bash, scp

I have this files:

```
A.class
A$1.class
A$2.class
```

And a bash script with something like:

```
for i in *; do
    scp "${i}" foo@bar:/tmp/;
done
```

This works fine. All three files are copied. The problem is with the following:

```
for i in *; do
    scp "${i}" foo@bar:/tmp/"${i}";
    scp "${i}" foo@bar:"/tmp/${i}";
    scp "${i}" "foo@bar:/tmp/${i}";
done
```

In any of this cases, SCP copies all the files, but to the same file *A.class*.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If the first solution works fine, what is the problem ?

Comment: We need to send the full path of the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `scp -v` shows some details about how scp works:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /tmp/A$2.class
Sending file modes: C0644 0 A$2.class
Sink: C0644 0 A$2.class
A$2.class                                     100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

Essentially, since scp runs over ssh, it needs a shell to execute your command, and since the `$` is not escaped, the remote shell interprets `$2` as an empty string, which makes the target name `A.class`.

There are two ways you could go about fixing this. First, you could just use the `*` glob in your scp command directly:

```
scp * foo@bar:/tmp/
```

But I'm pretty sure you have some other need to use a loop, so here's how to fix it in the loop:

```
for i in *; do
    scp "${i}" "foo@bar:'/tmp/${i}'"
done
```

Checking the output of `scp -v` now shows:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t '/tmp/A$2.class'
```

Success! The single quotes will prevent the remote shell from performing variable expansion.

UPDATE:
Since the argument is interpreted by the shell as an argument, you can do things like this:

```
scp foo@bar:'$(which ssh)' .
```

Or even more complicated shell pipelines that result in a filename. This is *not* a security issue, since if you can connect with scp, you can connect with ssh. But it might make things more convenient for someone.

Comment: Sir, awesome. Works like a charm. Didn't test the single quotes solutions assuming it would save the files as ${i}

Comment: The double quotes "protect" the single quotes from interpretation by your local shell. Another way to do it would be `foo@bar:\'/tmp/${i}\'`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use find for this:

```
find . -name A\*.class -print0|xargs -0 -i _PLACEHOLDER_ scp _PLACEHOLDER_ foo@bar:/tmp/_PLACEHOLDER_
```

The idea is to avoid shell expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by `"${i}"` being expanded locally to `A$1.class` and then sent to the remote which expands it to `A.class` as the `$1` is `""`. You an get round this with

```
scp "${i}" foo@bar:/tmp/'${i}';
```

Comment: You could also leave off the second `${i}` and just tell `scp` to put them in the `/tmp/` directory with the same name as they have now.

Comment: @Ladadadada: yes, the OP says this in the question!

Comment: Ah... so he does.  Wait... what's the problem again?

Comment: Understanding the difference I guess.